# Magento backend gives me a blank page when trying to edit order of more than $4,000

Tags: magento

Typically, the orders I have received have been less than $1,000, comprising of less than 10 products.  I had no problem editing those order (removing out of stock items, etc).

In the past month, I got one order for over $5,000 (35 products) and another for $4,000 (39 products).  When I go to the backend to sales>orders and click the order number, it shows the order, when I click "edit", it asks me "Are  you sure?" and when I click "ok" it gives me a blank page.

Help...

I am running Magento 1.4.1.1 on shared hosting

Comment: Please check the error/exception logs and post the error/exception message(s). It's impossible to answer your question without any error information at hand.

Comment: A typical cause of blank pages in PHP sites is memory running out. What is your site's [memory limit](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit)?

Comment: I get no error message.  It just shows a blank page.

Comment: Clockworkgeek - I am not quite sure if this is the right answer, but in the php.ini, it is set at 64M

Comment: 64M is far too less for magento check the system requirement page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running out of server resources:

- check your php configuration
- enable php error display from index.php
- see if your server meets Magento system requirements
- this error is also logged to your server php error log

Comment: Thank you.  I increased php memory_limit to 128 M, and it works for now.  Thank you Anton and clockworkgeek